# Creating a method for defining a area

Tags: java, swing

What is the best way to make all the coordinates in an area as on object, I need it for `MouseListener` so that when I click on an area that area gets repainted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Rectangle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) specifies an area.

Answer (score 0):

[`java.awt.geom.Area`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html), which conveniently implements the `Shape` interface, is a good choice.